# Check if values in list in different dataframe columns match?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to check each value in a list in two separate columns. My dataframe looks like:

```
 attribute         value1          value2
  Address       ['a','b','c']   ['a','b','c']
  Count         ['1', 2, 3]     ['1','2','3'] 
  Color         ['bl','cr','r'] ['bl','rd','gr']
```

I want a dataframe that looks like:

```
 attribute         value1          value2              match
  Address       ['a','b','c']   ['a','b','c']      [True, True, True]
  Count         ['1', 2, 3]     ['1','2','3']      [True, False, False]
  Color         ['bl','cr','r'] ['bl','rd','r']    [True, False, True]
```

I am trying to create a lambda statement but can't figure out the syntax:

```
if isinstance(data['value1'][0], list):
   for i in range(0, len(data.value1)):
       data['match'] = data['value2'].apply(lambda ls: [x for x in ls if x == data['value1'][i]])
```

Comment: Yes I have that but just missed it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

make each column to dataframe and chk vectorize and make list

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df1['value1'].tolist()).eq(pd.DataFrame(df1['value2'].tolist())).apply(list, axis=1)
```

out:

```
0      [True, True, True]
1    [True, False, False]
2     [True, False, True]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply function along with a lambda function will compares each element in the two lists. zip function will iterate over corresponding elements of value1 and value2 lists for each row and checks if they are equal.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'attribute': ['Address', 'Count', 'Color'],
        'value1': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', 2, 3], ['bl', 'cr', 'r']],
        'value2': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['bl', 'rd', 'r']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['match'] = df.apply(lambda row: [x == y for x, y in zip(row['value1'], row['value2'])], axis=1)

print(df)
attribute       value1       value2                 match
0   Address    [a, b, c]    [a, b, c]    [True, True, True]
1     Count    [1, 2, 3]    [1, 2, 3]  [True, False, False]
2     Color  [bl, cr, r]  [bl, rd, r]   [True, False, True]
```